# How to align siblings in a row in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm looking for a way to align the siblings of a row in this manner.

[image]

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code is not formatted properly due to a lack of time to answer this question. The below code is hardcoded, avoid it for making professional apps. Thanks

[image: See the below image]

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FirebaseProjectSelection extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Container(
              height: 100,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
                  top: BorderSide(),
                  bottom: BorderSide(),
                  left: BorderSide(),
                  right: BorderSide(),
                ),
              ),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 95,
                    width: 50,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                      border: Border(
                        top: BorderSide(),
                        bottom: BorderSide(),
                        left: BorderSide(),
                        right: BorderSide(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 50,
                      width: 50,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.orange,
                        border: Border(
                          top: BorderSide(),
                          bottom: BorderSide(),
                          left: BorderSide(),
                          right: BorderSide(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 50,
                      width: 50,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        border: Border(
                          top: BorderSide(),
                          bottom: BorderSide(),
                          left: BorderSide(),
                          right: BorderSide(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 50,
                      width: 50,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        border: Border(
                          top: BorderSide(),
                          bottom: BorderSide(),
                          left: BorderSide(),
                          right: BorderSide(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a `Row`, under the `Row`, group the items into two, the first `Container` and another `Container` that contains the three other items, in the second `Container`, it's child should be a `Stack`, then use `Positioned` widget to position all three children.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Row(
      children:[
        Container(
        width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.10),
        Container(
        width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.9,
        child:Stack(
        children:[
          Positioned(
          child:VerticallyAlighedAtStart()),
          Positioned(
          child:VerticallyAlighedAtEnd()),
          Positioned(
          child:VerticallyAlighedAtCenter())
        ])),
      ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

This should be enough to get you started, just learn how to use the `Positined` widget, here's a widget of a week video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EgtPleVwxBQ. also note `VerticallyAlighedAtStart`, `VerticallyAlighedAtEnd` & `VerticallyAlighedAtCenter` are just names I wrote, you need to replace it with your actual widgets.